# I want to open excel file as XLS from webpage?

Tags: excel, vba

```
<a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" onclick="window.location.pathname='/users/7206/normal_reponses.xls'" href="javascript:void(0)">XLS</a>
```

This code from webpage one button code.

How to call in VBA for above code or how to automate above step with VBA code. I want to open excel file as XLS from webpage?

Comment: and I want a Lamborghini, but alas!!. Meanwhile read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code has opened the website using an Internet Explorer object, called "ie" below, and there is only one element on the webpage with tag name = "a":

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).FireEvent ("onclick")
```